# Gnome Classic's clock on Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, clock

I really like the Gnome Classic's clock indicator. Is it possible to install/use it in Unity?

Example: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Install screenlets , then open screenlets-manager.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:screenlets/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screenlets
```

Comment: I have edited my message to better explain what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't use that indicator in Unity. Because that indicator is part of gnome2 (still used in gnome-classic) whereas Unity uses gnome3.

Comment: Even if I use it on Gnome Classic, Gnome 3? Maybe the unity panel just doesn't support applets?